# Yii2 Pass Dynamic Model to View

Tags: php, dynamic, model, yii2

I have a Create Payslip page and I want to pass a dynamic model since this page/view requires more than one earning items.

My `actionCreateNew` in my **controller**:

```
$session = Yii::$app->session;  
$model = new Payslip();
$model->user_id = $id;
$model1 = new EarningDetails();
$model2 = new DeductionDetails();
$items = PayrollItems::find()->where(['store_id' => $id])->andwhere(['active' => 1])->andwhere(['payroll_type' => 'Earnings'])->all();
$count = count($items);
for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++){
    $earning[$i] = new EarningDetails();
    $earning[$i]->earning_item_id = $items[$i];
}
```

and here's my `return` statement in the same action controller:

```
return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
    'model1' => $model1,
    'model2' => $model2,
    'items' => $items, 
]);
```

and in my **view**:

```
<?php 
    $earnings = PayrollItems::find()->where(['store_id' => $session['store_id']])->orwhere(['store_id' => null])->where(['payroll_type' => 'Earnings'])->all();
    //$earningslistData = ArrayHelper::map($earnings,'payroll_items_id', 'payroll_name');
    $earningslistData = ArrayHelper::map($earnings,'payroll_items_id',function($items, $defaultValue) {
        return $items->payroll_name;
    });
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        echo $form->field($earning[$i], 'earning_item_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => $earningslistData,
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select an Earning ', 'id' => 'earning_item'],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]);
    }
?>
```

Problem is, how do I return a dynamic model? So I could use it in my view. In my return statement above, there's no `$earning` since it's a dynamic model and I don't know to return it.

If you have any other implementation about dynamic models, please pleas let me know.

Comment: I don't think it can be done, you can create public property in controller or static property in some helper and use it for $earnings storing

Comment: Did you try sending the `$earning` variable to the view just like the `$model` variable in the return statement?

Comment: How do I send it in its dynamic form? I'm no yii2 master. So, sorry for such dumb questions.

Comment: But `$earnings` is not a `yii\base\DynamicModel` it's just a list of `PayrollItems` :-/

Answer (score 4):

You're halfway there.

First off, there is no Dynamic Model in your snippet, just an array of models. A Dynamic Model is [an actual thing in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel.html).

Now, if you want the `$earning` array you created in the controller to be available in the view, just add an entry to the array in the call to `render()`:

```
return $this->render('create', [
    'model' => $model,
    'model1' => $model1,
    'model2' => $model2,
    'items' => $items, 
    'earning' => $earning,
]);
```

You may also want to move the definition of `$earningslistData` to the controller and pass it to the view in the same manner.